# Não consigo implementar um @Foreach em MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento ASP.NET MVC e preciso de uma ajuda.
Não estou conseguindo criar um `Foreach`.
Segue abaixo meu código.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Fornecedores)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Codigo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.NomeFantasia)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.RazaoSocial)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.CNPJ)
        </td>           
    </tr>
}
```

Minha *model* é essa:

```
 public partial class Fornecedor
{
    public Fornecedor()
    {
        this.Entrada = new HashSet<Entrada>();
        this.Produto = new HashSet<Produto>();
    }

    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Nome fantasia é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Razão Social é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inscrição Estadual é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string IE { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CNPJ é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }

    public Nullable<bool> Ativo { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Entrada> Entrada { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produto { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Fornecedor> Fornecedores { get; set; }
}
```

Meu *Controller*:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

O erro é o seguinte:
**Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto**

O que está faltando?
Preciso de ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está a dar porque tens de enviar a lista de dados para a view, do tipo de dados que recebes no `Model` do lado da view.

Sendo assim, tens de enviar uma lista de dados:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var fornecedores = db.Fornecedor.ToList();
    return View(fornecedores);
}
```

Ainda assim, deduzo que te falte instanciar o `Model` na View:

```
@Model IEnumerable<OTeuProjeto.Models.Fornecedor>
```

Comment: Desde já muito obrigado, você já me ajudou muito.
Aparentemente está quase certo.
Agora estou tentando resolver um erro que está dando quando o Debug passa na linha:
'var fornecedores = db.Fornecedores.ToList();'

O erro que está dando é esse aqui:
An exception of type **"System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException"
occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:**

Comment: Muito possivelmente é porque não tens uma chave primária definida na entidade `fornecedor`. No model onde tens o campo `codigo`, coloca `public int FornecedorID { get; set; }`

Comment: Coloquei um DataAnnotations [Key] para todas as Chaves primárias e não  deu mais o erro, porém não fez SELECT de nenhum fornecedor que está no banco.
Estou procurando o porque, caso puder ajudar.

Comment: Sim, também resulta. Ao fazer debug o que te dá a lista no `fornecedores` no controller?

Comment: A lista returna NULL e diz que "A Enumeração não gerou resultados"

Será que tenho que criar uma lista no Controller?

Comment: a variável está a retornar toda a lista que tens na entidade `Fornecedor`, tens a certeza que tens dados na bd?

Comment: Existe dados no banco, mas não retorna nada e também não dá erro.
Não estou usando _Where_ então não existe filtros.

Comment: Sim, a partida tem de ficar assim por não existir filtros...

Comment: O erro pode está no SELECT que o linq-to-sql está fazendo.
`SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Codigo] AS [Codigo], 
    [Extent1].[NomeFantasia] AS [NomeFantasia], 
    [Extent1].[RazaoSocial] AS [RazaoSocial], 
    [Extent1].[IE] AS [IE], 
    [Extent1].[CNPJ] AS [CNPJ], 
    [Extent1].[Ativo] AS [Ativo], 
    [Extent1].[Fornecedor_Codigo] AS [Fornecedor_Codigo]
    FROM [dbo].[Fornecedors] AS [Extent1]}`

Repare na minha ultima linha de código
Minha table chama Fornecedor e não Fornecedors.

Ele deve estar fazendo a pluralização via Entity Framework

Comment: Aconselho te a fazer um novo post com essa mesma questão.. Não estou a perceber qual o problema

Answer (score 0):

Você não estava fazendo nada em sua `controller`, este é o problema.
Você tem que usar a `controller` pra, primeiramente instanciar a sua classe que cria as funções e métodos que vai querer usar, e depois tem que chamar essas funções para essa `controller`. e após isso tem que enviar ela para `view`.

Na sua classe `controller` está vazia.

Vou dar um exemplo, sua `controller`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        caminhodaclasse.nome_da_classe_que_quer_acessar = new caminhodaclasse();
        nome_da_classe_que_quer_acessar.funcao_da_sua_model();
        return View();
    }
```